# port Viewer Image passing at runtime

Tags: c#, report, reportviewer

Using **Visual Studio Ultimate 2012**. **C Sharp .Net4.0**.

Hi guys, Here I am saving an image to my **C drive**.

```
if (File.Exists("C:\\LabelImages\\TypeImage1.Png"))
   {                  
       File.Delete(@"C:\\LabelImages\\TypeImage1.Png");
       picNewType.Image.Save(@"C:\\LabelImages\\TypeImage1.Png");
                //reportViewer1.Reset();
               // reportViewer1.Refresh();
   }
   else
   {
       if (!(picNewType.Image == null))
       {                   
           picNewType.Image.Save(@"C:\\LabelImages\\TypeImage1.Png");
                    //reportViewer1.Reset();
                    //reportViewer1.Refresh();
       }
   }
```

Then i have a method that sets the **reports paramters**.

```
public virtual IList<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter> NewReportSetup(string part, string batch, string locn, string wheel, string gear, string length,
                                string fits, string newbar, string newbarnum, string abs)
    {
        IList<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter> parameters = new List<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter>();
        parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramPart", part));
        parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramBatch", batch));
        parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramLocn", locn));
        parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramWheel", wheel));
        parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramGear", gear));
        parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramLength", length));
        parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramABS", abs));
        parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramBuyer", fits));
        parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramBarCode", newbar));
        parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("paramBartxt", newbarnum));
        //parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("path", filepath.AbsoluteUri));

        return parameters;
    }
```

Then my report has an Image that is set to **"embeded"** and value is an **import** to the location on the C drive.

Now this loads the image which is great, but if the image is **changed at runtime**, the report **does not change**.

Is there a way to **force the import to update**?

I have looked into other methods without luck, such as setting the image as **external** and using **"file:///"** but only ever recieve a **"x"** symbol.

Basically Im running out of ideas as to what to do so help would be great.

Many thanks!

**UPDATE::** ok wow no replys at all....
well ive been trying some other stuff.

Setting the image to external on the report and in code, then passing the path to the file as a paramter, then set the value of the image to be the parameter and all i have been getting is the "X" symbol. Im hoing Nuts here theres got to be an easy solution for this?

**UPDATE!!** 
Ok ive gone through alot of sources all saying the same thing and that this should work, but for some reason im still gettin a red x and no image for the following:

```
string filepath = @"file:///C:\LabelImages\TypeImage1.Png";
parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("path", filepath));
```

then in my report i have a parameter "path" that is set to the value of the image on the report in the following expresson

```
=Parameters!path.Value
```

All this combined together should Get me an Image. Source is set to External The MIME is set to Png. Not only this but Ive also set this aswell:

```
 reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
 reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Then after this i set the paramters:

```
 IList<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter> param = new List<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter>();

            IList<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter> param = new List<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter>();

            param = reportshaft.NewReportSetup(txtNewPart.Text.ToString(),
                txtBatch.Text.ToString(), txtLocation.Text.ToString(), txtWheel.Text.ToString(), txtGear.Text.ToString(), txtLength.Text.ToString(),
                txtFits.Text.ToString(), txtNewBar.Text.ToString(), txtNewBarNum.Text.ToString(), txtABS.Text.ToString(), filepath.ToString());

            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();;
```

So why is it im still getting no image? im losing my mind here really need some one to post something.

Even when i hard code the following:

```
="file:///C:\LabelImages\TypeImage1.Png"
```

So im really stuck here, no error occuring just no image just the little x in a box.

Or is there a way to just re-embed the image at button click if i set this up as embeded?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had almost the same problem referencing External Images... The answer is only 2 slashes after "file" it seems.

**File://C:\Path\To\My File\Logo.jpg**

The sample below is taken from one of my working reports (Report Builder 3.0, SQL Server 2012)

[image]